# How to get number of words on a web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to get total number of WORDS on a web page. I know about the `System.Net.WebClient` class. But it's `DownloadString()` method return the whole HTML markup where as what I need is only the TEXT so that I can figure out the number of words.

Any ideas/suggestions welcome.

Comment: How consistent are the web pages you wish to process? Do any use CSS or JavaScript to hide or generate content? If content is sometimes hidden or generated dynamically, would you want the word count to be adjusted? Do you want things like the text in alt/title attributes being counted (e.g. the words that appear in a mouse-over on an image)?

Comment: Points noted! Thanks Daniel. I just want the text visible on the webpage leaving all the HTML tags at that very moment when the code is run.

Comment: Note that the HtmlAgilityPack approach (or similar) will count words that are not necessarily visible to the user (e.g. hidden by CSS rules) and won't count any content generated in the browser using JavaScript.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, I just made a sample app using HTMLAgilityPack and encountered that problem. Any work around you can think of?

Comment: I've posted a suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net).  It allows you to apply XPath expressions to an HTML document.

You want to find all text nodes and then count the words. `//text()` is the XPath to get all text nodes.

Comment: How does HAP help with this though? When I do something like `foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()")) { var s = node.InnerText ; }` I still get a bunch of html/css attributes in my `s` result.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) to download and parse the HTML document.

You can then query the document object and extract the inner text of all nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I see two choices:

1. Use a html library to parse the string into a dom like tree.
2. Use some simple text based hacks

Option 1 is obviously cleaner, but introduces additional dependencies on third party libraries.

There are several steps:

1. Remove tags(with content) whose content you don't like. For example scripts and stylesheets.
2. Remove all other tags keeping their content/extract the text from the remaining tags
3. Split the remainder using the string.Split function with all whitespaces as split chars, and the option to ignore empty result strings enabled
4. Count the number of entries `Split` returned.

Obviously this doesn't work well for all languages. For example Japanese/Chinese don't have spaces between words.

Comment: It's not fast, but if you can afford downloading a string you probably can afford this too.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.wordcounttool.com/ ... this is the most basic way i know

Answer (score 0):

If you need to count only those words actually visible to the user (i.e. ignoring content hidden by CSS and including content created dynamically by JavaScript) then you will probably need to automate a browser or browser control.

It may be possible to do this entirely with client-side JavaScript:

1. Load the first web page into an iframe.
2. After everything is fully loaded, interrogate the runtime DOM to extract only the content that is visible to the user.
3. Write the results into the outer pages content area.
4. Repeat for the next web page.

Answer (score 0):

okay so since the text hack in not here I'll try it quick and dirty js way hope this helps someone.

```js
let wordCount = document.body.innerText.split(/\s/).length

//other stuff to copy pasta :)
let words = document.body.innerText.split(/\s/)

    /**
     * Makes the elements unique by converting to a set and then back to an array.
     * @param array
     * @return {any[]}
     */
    function uniqueArray(array) {
        return Array.from(new Set(array));
    }

let uniqueWords = uniqueArray(words);
// todo count frequency adding Term frequency analysis 
// and your ready to do page indexing by word tags
```