# How many times a word is present in a web page using htmlagility C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am a developing a C# application which can scrape the contents of a web page and return all the words of the page. I am using HTMLAGILITY pack for it.

I want to know how can i know how many times a word is present in a web page after scraping the contents of the page.

Comment: The purpose of this site is to help you wrote code, not to write it for you. Post the code you have tried and explain what how it doesn't do what you want.

Comment: You know that it's `Stackoverflow` not `YourPrivateCodeFactory` site right ? You should show us an examples of what you tried. (Btw it's not understood why using HtmlAgilityPack for this, a straight search count will suffice).

Comment: I am asking for a way to do it. I think there's no need to post my code for it.

Comment: @Nisthar You should show some effort that you have try to solve your problem first by your self, then when you fail to find solution, come and make it a question. And there you show what you have try and where you fail, what you did not understand etc.

Comment: for example if you google "HTMLAGILITYpack count words" you can found all ready many solutions.... if none of them work then you can come again here -> here is one similar : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096051/how-to-get-number-of-words-on-a-web-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could treat the whole page/web request as a string and do something like this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546166.aspx

It might not be efficient and it would search CSS classes and everything else but it might be a starting point.

Else you need to use the agility pack and scrape through each not and check each bit of public text .

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Comment: How to scrape only the text ? Without capturing the html and css code. I know that i could use DocumentNode.SelectNode('//a').innerText. But How can i extract text without a tag?

Comment: I don't think you can, you have to scrape through the whole thing, iterate over the nodes and processes inner test.